# Use swatches and not the color picker widget

Tags: 7

The Color core modules allows for a user to perform css color overrides via the theme settings page. This is handy for exposing the means for users to update color specifications without touching a line of CSS code. I've successfully integrated the Color module with an Omega 3.x subtheme. However, we have a range of branded color swatches that I'd like to make available to our users, rather than the too-broad color picker that the color module uses.

So; I'd like to swap (it can be additive, i.e., use one or the other) the Drupal color picker with a pane of swatches that I can configure.

How to do so?

Comment: Taking this on is not trivial: https://drupal.org/node/1236098 Also, supporting alpha values and 'transparent' specification would helpful. The current version of the color module may not be worth the effort.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question - You should try the [color field module](https://drupal.org/project/color_field) -

> Color Field is simple field that use a hexadecimal notation (HEX) for
>   the combination of Red, Green, and Blue color values (RGB).

This uses the [jquery simple color widget](https://github.com/recurser/jquery-simple-color)

[image]

and you can add your colors directly in as hexadecimal codes when you setup the field:

[image]

Comment: Too bad, it sounds perfect, EXCEPT you have to enable support by adding a specific field type to the content type. This, of course, is unavailable as a color module.

Comment: ah - i see you've updated the question to be specific to the core color module. Try this tutorial then: http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/becoming-friends-with-the-drupal-color-module-part-1/2011-11-25

Comment: Yes, that page was helpful with integrating color module with the omega subtheme which I've already done. I don't see any references for changing the color picker to a swatch-based picker, though?